# How to trigger an event with MongoDB when my query is not returning any document anymore with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some documents in a collection like:

```
{
    tag: '0807210067703121',
    actualStatus: 'onBranch',
    barcode: '0677'
},
{
    tag: '0807210067703122',
    actualStatus: 'onBranch',
    barcode: '0677'
},
{
    tag: '0807210066603123',
    actualStatus: 'onBranch',
    barcode: '0666'
},
{
    tag: '0807210066603124',
    actualStatus: 'onBranch',
    barcode: '0666'
},
{
    tag: '0807210066603125',
    actualStatus: 'onBranch',
    barcode: '0666'
}
```

When `actualStatus` becomes `sold` for all my documents that have `barcode: '0666'` I want to trigger an event. Is there any way to do this with nodeJs using mongodb.

I can make a query each time a document actualStatus becomes sold to see how many still onBranch but this will increase the load of the server a lot!

Comment: You can try using Change Streams. Its a MongoDB feature and is available with replica sets or sharded cluster only.

Comment: @prasad_ yes but the problem with it, is that it will trigger for each change made in document I want to trigger if it does not find any document

Comment: I have  replica sets, I know it is the way to go but does not know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mongodb atlas dashboard you can create a trigger as describe in the picture

[image]

and then I have added a function that will trigger each 30 minutes but you can trigger it when a specific event is triggered like actualStatus becomes 'sold'

```
exports = async function() {
  /**
   * includedBarcodes is the list of barcodes that will be included in the notification
   */
  const includedBarcodes = [
    "25631","44861","43861", // ...
  ];
  /**
   * 
   * @param arr Array of objects to remove duplicates from it
   * @param prop the property to be checked for duplicates
   * @returns Array of objects without duplicates
   */
  const removeDuplicates = (arr, prop) => arr.reduce(
    (unique, item) => unique.map(item => item[prop]).includes(item[prop]) ? unique: [...unique, item] ,[]
  );

  try {
    /**
     * get the database and the collection
     */
    const zeroStock = context.services.get("clusterName");
    const db = zeroStock.db("dbName");
    const stamps = db.collection("productstamps");
    /**
     * get all sold stamps in the last 30 minutes
     */
    const date = new Date();
    date.setMinutes((new Date()).getMinutes() - 30);
    const soldStamps = await (stamps.aggregate([
      { $addFields: { elmMatch: { $arrayElemAt: ['$status', -1] }, } },
      { $match: {
        'elmMatch.soldByBranchID': { $exists: true },
        'elmMatch.date': { $gt: date },
        barcode: { $in: includedBarcodes }
      }},
      { $sort: { 'elmMatch.soldByBranchID': -1 } }
    ]).toArray());
    if (soldStamps.length) { 
      /**
       * now you can get the branches that sold the stamps
       * and the barcodes of the sold stamps
       * you can send the notification or make any query you want
       */
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
  }
}
```